# SonarQube Vulnerability

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, webapi

I am new to using SonarQube and I am trying to fix some vulnerabilities but not sure how.I also attached the image showing the sonarQube issue. My hunch tells me I need to validate the selectedFileName parameter somehow. Your thoughts and ideas are greatly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{selectedFileName}/{selectedTruckModel}/{selectedTravelTimeSettingName}/{selectedCorneringSettingId}/{selectedImportTemplateSettingId}/{selectedPropertiesName}")]
public IEnumerable<RPMTravelTimeTest> CalculateTravelTimeFromSegmentFile(string selectedFileName, string selectedTruckModel, string selectedTravelTimeSettingName, string selectedCorneringSettingId, string selectedImportTemplateSettingId,string selectedPropertiesName)
{
        var travelTimeTestList = new RPMTravelTimeTestCollection();
        travelTimeTestList.LoadTravelTimeTestBySegmentFile(_isHaaSProduction,
                                                           config.Value.StandardHaulageConnectString,
                                                           selectedTruckModel,
                                                           selectedTravelTimeSettingName,
                                                           selectedCorneringSettingId,
                                                           selectedImportTemplateSettingId,
                                                           selectedFileName,
                                                           selectedPropertiesName);

    return travelTimeTestList;
}
```

[image: SonarQube issue]

Comment: Can you provide some information about the class that's being called?

Comment: Are you certain that your code could never be manipulated into serving up the contents of a particularly sensitive file?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this to the best of my ability.

The SonarScanner here identifies that you are creating an instance of a class RPMTravelTimeTestCollection and building the object directly with user input data with the LoadTravelTimeTestBySegmentFile method. The actual issue SonarScanner identifies and decides that is security-sensitive is the selectedFileName string variable that is given by the caller of the HTTP GET method which you have declared.

I cannot know how you handle the selectedFilename user input but there might be a chance that you are not secured from path traversal vulnerabilities, more info here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal.

You could implement input validation in the LoadTravelTimeTestBySegmentFile method which validates that the variable selectedFilename is not fed path traversal characters or arbitrary file extensions but to avoid a faulty validation implementation using Regular Expressions or similar techniques I would instead use a whitelisting implementation like the following:

```
public bool ValidateFileName(string fileName, string destDirectory)
{
    // destDirectory could be "C:/Users/example/App_Data/traveltimesfolder/"
    // fileName could be traveltimes.csv

    string destFileName = Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirectory, fileName));
    string fullDestDirPath = Path.GetFullPath(destDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    return destFileName.StartsWith(fullDestDirPath, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

The code above will return false if the user tries to use path traversal characters to access folders outside of the provided destDirectory you specified with the method parameter. You should enrich the validation above by adding file extension checks and other type of rules to perform secure file reading.

You could even go ahead and write some Unit Tests to test with malicious input data fed from a list of payloads, you can find various path traversal payloads here: https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists.

If the vulnerability persists in the SonarQube web interface then set the vulnerability as fixed via the web interface explaining in the comment section what type of security measures you took to secure the handling of the variable.